# Recovering lost memory in Macbook

Tags: windows, macbook, boot-camp

I had installed Windows-10 via boot camp in my MacBook pro (128 GBs). When I tried to **Uninstall the Windows** using Boot Camp, the process did not complete and threw some error (not enough memory error).

During the uninstallation process, the Windows partition got corrupted. The Windows partition is not visible anywhere (e.g. Disk Utility, `diskutil list` command).

**PROBLEM:** I am not able to get the hard-disk memory back, which was assigned to Windows (around 50 GBs).

**QUESTION:** Now I am looking the best possible way to get my memory back. Will the following work? And, what do I need to keep in mind? And, what is the complete procedure?

I am planning to do the following steps:

1. Create Time-machine of my current Macbook
2. Open the Mac in recovery mode
3. re-install Mac OS
4. Load previous settings back using Time-Machine

***How the step-3 regarding reinstall will work? Do I need to download Mac OS somewhere in a disk beforehand?***

Comment: Take a look at this : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305172/cant-delete-bootcamp-partition

Comment: @shinjijai: I had a look at that answer. But I am not able to understand it. I have posted the results of `Diskutil list` command in my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I remove a Boot Camp partition from my MacBook?](https://superuser.com/questions/814/can-i-remove-a-boot-camp-partition-from-my-macbook)

Comment: @Moab: I wish you had read my question properly before suggesting those links. I know its possible to remove windows but I am facing some issues (as mentioned in the post).

Comment: If you don't want to play in terminal, then you need a paid solution. Software recs are frowned on as answers, so just as a comment; try [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) & see this QA for some of the things it can do... https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/352567/85275

Answer (score 0):

This question has been posted over on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) more times than I can remember. The same basic answer is to enter the command given below.

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

After entering this command, Windows may still appear in the Startup Manager and/or System Preferences. If so, you may want to ask a new question with regard to fixing that error.